# Error in Executing the Simulink model 'Error in port widths or dimensions.'

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have the Simulink model. I want to execute the model. But while executing it, the model shows the error mentioned below:

Error:Error in port widths or dimensions. 'Output Port 1' of 'Climate_standalone/CtClimate_TL_swc/S-function frame/TriggerPort' has 2 elements.  This port does not accept the dimensions (or orientation) specified by the output signal.

The mentioned error directs to the Block called TriggerPort as shown in the image below:
[image]

I want to ask:

1. How can I solve the error?
2. What does mean by '**?(2)**' mentioned next to the TriggerPort in the image?

I have opened the TriggerPort's Block Parameters but i cannot see any useful information. Let me know if I am missing something or doing any mistake.

[image]

Comment: it means that whatever you connected on the right is not expecting/ does not support an input of size 1x2 or 2x1  (i can't tell). To solve it you need to share the destination block where the line is connected

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question and represented the Block Parameters of the TriggerPort Block